# Nested array date matching not working in mongo

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

I have collection model with below schema:

```
{
        "id":"122HSHDJS2333222222",
        "name":"Item1",
        "image":"",
        "is_deleted":false,
        "item_blocked_on":[
            {
                "start_date":"2017-02-15T18:30:00.000Z",
                "end_date":"2017-02-24T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "start_date":"2017-01-16T18:30:00.000Z",
                "end_date":"2017-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Above model represents that these "items" are blocked , for these start to end date , hence not available for display

Now in my case , the USER gonna send "from_date" and "end_date" from client side.
What I want is , the query should return "items" which are "available" for display for user start and end date.

My query , which is returning WRONG response :-

```
{
        where:{
            and:[
                {
                    and:[
                        {
                            or:[{"item_blocked_on.start_date": {"gt": new Date(from_date)}},{"item_blocked_on.end_date": {"lt": new Date(from_date)}}],
                        },
                        {
                            or:[{"item_blocked_on.start_date": {"gt": new Date(end_date)}},{"item_blocked_on.end_date": {"lt": new Date(end_date)}}],
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "is_deleted":false
                }

            ]
        }
    };
```

Please let me know if i am not being clear or doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to your requirement you can easily use the $elemMatch as shown in example.

```
     router.post('/data_find', function (req, res) {
            var database = req.Collection;
            var start_date = req.body.start_date;
            var end_date = req.body.end_date;
            if (start_date.length > 0 && end_date.length > 0) {
database.find({ "item_blocked_on.start_date": {$gte: start_date}, "item_blocked_on.end_date": {$lt: end_date},function(err,user){
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({status: 0, message: err});
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        res.json({status: 0, msg: "not found"});
                    }
                    res.json({status: 1, id: user._id, message: " success"});
                })
            } else {
                res.json({status: 0, msg: "Invalid Fields"});
            }
        });
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response , I think you my requirements wrong. The "items" which are booked for "date range" should not come in the output , can not use `$eq` as datetime can vary.

Comment: your question is right,this query works for you.
database.find({ "item_blocked_on.start_date": {$gte: start_date}, "item_blocked_on.end_date": {$lt: end_date}}; updated the code as well